# Vue update state using array of item value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Hello everyone**

I have a simple application where I try to visualize insertion sort algorithm using vue and I managed to write a function that sorts list of items and return an array of each step of the algorithm and the last array of this array is the fully sorted version of original array, so what I want is to update the state and set the original unsorted array with each value of the array of steps that returned from the function;

**here's my insertion sort function**

```
const insertionSort = (unsortedItems) => {
let sortedList = [...unsortedItems];
let sortingProcess = [];
for (let i = 1; i < sortedList.length; i++) {
   let current = sortedList[i];
   let j = i - 1;
   while (j >= 0 && sortedList[j] > current) {
      sortedList[j + 1] = sortedList[j];
      j--;
      sortingProcess.push(sortedList);
    }
    sortedList[j + 1] = current;
    sortingProcess.push(sortedList);
   }
   return sortingProcess;
 };

 export default insertionSort;
```

**and here I'm trying to update my state**

```
insertionSort(this.unsortedList).forEach(round =>
    setTimeout(() => (this.unsortedList = round), 600)
  );
```

I expected the above code to update my state every 600 ms but as I click sort button the array instantly sorted and I don't get to see each step of sorting process. so what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Vue specific question. It's related to one of the most popular javascript interview question. `forEach(`) is looping over array and setting a timeout on each item, because it doesn't have a closure scope. All items are going to be executed at the same time: 600ms from now. The possible solution is:

```
insertionSort(this.unsortedList).forEach((round, i) =>
    setTimeout(() => (this.unsortedList = round), i * 600)
  );
```

Read more [here](https://medium.com/@axionoso/watch-out-when-using-settimeout-in-for-loop-js-75a047e27a5f)

Comment: still get same result the array is sorted as soon as i click sort

Comment: so you want it to update recursively, right? You can try to put this logic to watcher and listen to unsortedList.

Comment: sorry your solution works, I just have a bug in my algorithm function